# Broken First Post review audit

Tags: bug, review-queues, deleted-answers

I just got an [audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5503664) for a (deleted) answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031621/add-custom-component-to-palette-intellij-idea) question.  Tried flagging it got an error.  Tried voting down got an error.  Tried commenting and got an error.  Lastly I tried clicking No Action Needed; just to see if it would acknowledge a deliberate fail.  It didn't, instead I just got bumped to to the no more first posts available page.

The audit link doesn't show the answer any more, but I took screenshots of the 2nd and 3rd errors I got and combined them into this composite image.  Hopefully this is enough for someone to track down why the system zapped the answer (which I assume was long gone) out from under my review before I could complete the audit.
[image]

Comment: Was it an audit though? I'm willing to bet it wasn't, and it just handled the deletion of a post *while you're reviewing it* badly.

Comment: @hichris123 that possibility never occurred to me.  Should be easy enough to check by someone with 10k privileges though.

Comment: Actually, if it was a regular review; shouldn't the names of the people who did kill it show up?  And I'd've expected a "other people already finished this review" message.  Either way something is slightly broken.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was not an audit. The post was simply deleted while you were reviewing it. Though in that event, review could tell you that the post is no longer eligible for review in a more graceful manner.

It would be nice if it detected that deletion state and gave you an audit-like message along the lines of:

> This post was removed while you were looking at it. Unfortunately, further actions are not allowed and you will not get credit for the review. Please continue onto the next post.

It could be shown similar to the pass/fail message - just the text with a Next button, so at least you know what happened.

Comment: I completely agree, but basically the error says: "Cannot add comments to this post; it may be **locked, deleted, or frozen**." So it's not difficult to see what has happened.