# First Posts Review

Tags: discussion, review-suspension

I have been barred for a month from reviewing any posts because I [apparently] didn't do any action to the following post:

> https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5713556

I wrote a comment to this post while in reviewer modus asking the poster to provide a summary of the link's contents. It was something like the following:

> Please provide a better description of the solution than a mere link. Its contents could change or be unavailable in the future.

Hitting the submit button told me that the comment could not be added as the post was deleted, so after trying a second time I hit the "No action needed" button and am now not able to review any posts for a full month.

Admittedly, the length of my review ban implies that I have failed other reviews in the past but I find this review to be rather unfair, since I did want to add a comment but the system didn't let me. In this case, should I have skipped the post (the "Skip" button) rather than hitting "No action needed"? I frankly thought that the post was already dealt with and that it thus needed no further attention, as the button name suggests.

I had a similar issue on the last review, which cost me a two week review ban. I've taken it as a very serious warning and have really taken my time to read the posts thoroughly ever since and have added feedback if I had any minor suggestions to the posts, so being disallowed from reviewing posts for a full month now seems really unfair.

Comment: I got sufficiently frustrated with the audit system that I simply dropped out of reviewing. If everyone who had problems with it did that, either there would be enough reviewers who do not find it frustrating, and all would be well, or the system would have to be improved. Think of a month off from reviewing as an opportunity do other, more constructive, things with the time you would have spent reviewing.

Comment: If you hit a 30 day review ban... that means you've hit a 2 day and a 7 day review ban *in the last 30 days alone*. [See the explanation on review bans](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190562/237685).

Comment: Seems like a bug with the review system. It should make it look like you successfully posted a comment even though it was deleted. But the indication that it was deleted should have informed you that it was in fact an audit, and you should have clicked a button to pass the audit. I think that your previous 2-week ban was manually triggered by a mod. Such bans are triggered in edge cases (like when you are doing bad reviews but are still somehow managing to pass the review audits).

Comment: Like Patricia, I don't use the review queue either. I find it too frustrating. That doesn't mean, though, that you can't continue to improve the site the old-fashioned way. But to be fair, I disagree with you here: that post *needed* attention. Doing nothing is not a reasonable choice. "No action needed" means the post is fine; it was not. It really needed to be deleted.

Comment: Why adding a comment when there is an appropriate delete reason for that saying the same thing? (link-only answer)

Comment: @CodyGray: He's already been told the post is deleted.  What action could be required?  *Undeleting* it?  It's absolutely the case that no further action is required; leaving it the way it is (deleted) is the right thing.  He isn't the only one who has posted on Meta about this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Review question's being [deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268969/review-audit-on-answer-that-had-its-question-deleted-out-from-under-it) [do](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268270/broken-first-post-review-audit) [leak](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193830/why-doesnt-attempting-to-edit-count-as-a-pass-for-a-review-audit) [through](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236382/attempting-to-vote-on-a-comment-revealed-that-an-answer-was-a-low-quality-queue) in some places (and I've gotten burned by this before myself); but any time that happens it's almost always an audit question (although occasionally a mod will nuke a regular review post out from under you) and the safest thing to do is to start mashing buttons until you find one that it accepts as a review vote of this-is-crap-burn-it-with-fire.

If you can't, the safest thing to do is to click skip; and then report is on Meta as a broken review.  Trying the accept option to see if it errors or causes you to fail the review would be a bit more information for the bug report; but, especially if you've had another recent suspension, is playing with fire.

Comment: Really, once the message that the post is deleted pops up, the Leave It Alone (aka "No Action Needed") button ought to change to "Leave It Deleted" and become a pass action.

Comment: @BenVoigt I like the way you think. Great comments on here. ☮️❤️